# How to change the overflow button when in CAB?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, contextual-action-bar

I have 2 different backgrounds to the Action bar. One light and another dark. One for the default title and another for the CAB (when some of the elements are selected/activated).

I would like to have 2 different overflow when in those different states.
I tried the selector but couldn't find the state to represent when in CAB mode.

**Any idea how to provide different overflow buttons?**

- On a more general note, where can I start exploring the Action Bar so I could find the answers myself instead of finding bits and pieces all over the inet? I would expect Google/Android to provide a starting point. I guess I just didn't find it.

Comment: If I could find actionbar's layout xml and the corresponding attributes, everything would be easier.

Comment: I found the style setting for the overflow button, but it's general and not per state: `android:actionOverflowButtonStyle`. How can I change it programmatically?