# How to know if an Android actionbar's action icon is on the top bar or the bottom bar (split)?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have a split action bar, where the top bar is dark and the bottom bar (split) is light.

Consequently, I'd like to show a contrast action icons: Light icons in the top dark bar and dark icons in the bottom light bar.

The problem is knowing if the actions should be painted on the top or bottom bar. How can I know that?

Another option is to know whether the action bar is currently split. How do I know that?

Thanks.

Comment: There's a difficulty doing split with contrast bars, because of the overflow icon. Action icons can be changed, but the overflow cannot. See question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934825/how-to-change-the-overflow-button-when-in-cab

Answer (score 8):

Simple. You use boolean values. By default you'll have a split ActionBar if the screen width is smaller than 400dp. So in your values folder you can put:

**/values/bools.xml:**

```
<resources>
    <bool name="split_action_bar">true</bool>
</resources>
```

and in your values-sw400dp you put the following.

**/values-sw400dp/bools.xml:**

```
<resources>
    <bool name="split_action_bar">false</bool>
</resources>
```

Now you can set your icon based on that value:

```
boolean isActionBarSplitted = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.split_action_bar);
if(isActionBarSplitted){
      // set light icon
}
else{
     // set dark icon
}
```

**Edit:**

Actually forget what I wrote, you don't need to create your own boolean value to check it. There is already one declared(which is the one the ActionBar uses to determine if it is a handset device or a tablet).
If you're targeting Android HC+, then you can access the default ActionBars value:
`android.R.bool.split_action_bar_is_narrow`, if you are using ActionBarSherlock:
`R.bool.abs_split_action_bar_is_narrow`.
Found [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/bools.xml) for the default ActionBar, [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/library/res/values/abs__bools.xml) your ABS.

Comment: Thanks. How do you know it's 400dp?

Comment: Wow, great. Can you please share the name of the class and method?

Comment: Thanks but "android.R.bool." doesn't offer anything. When I type "android.R.bool.split_action_bar_is_narrow, i get a compilation error. See screenshot: http://ppl.ug/uQE38Eg4ONc/

Comment: I found something. It seems that split_action_bar_is_narrow is internal: com.android.internal.R.bool.split_action_bar_is_narrow. Dead end?

Comment: Hmm, I did not know that this wasn't part of the public API. I tested it out with the ActionBarSherlock boolean and that did work. Try this here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8683466/1333975

Comment: Did the following and it worked: int id = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("split_action_bar_is_narrow", "bool", "android");
boolean isSplit = getResources().getBoolean(id);

Comment: The problem is that now I don't know if this identifier exists in all Android 4+. I found this identifier was added on April 2011 (https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/9b4bee0f14bbd137b0797127aff2df46a6321ec5). Is this identifier part of every Android 4+???

Comment: @kilaka If you're using ABS, you might want to use the compatibility method `getResources_getBoolean(mActivity, R.bool.abs__split_action_bar_is_narrow);`, since the qualifier used by this resource (w480dp) is not directly supported by Android versions older than 3.2, therefore, it would return always the default value, `true`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the library you are using.

For the new **Appcompat** : check the value of `R.bool.abc_split_action_bar_is_narrow`:

```
boolean split = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.abc_split_action_bar_is_narrow);
```

For **ActionBarShelock** : import the `ResourcesCompat` class from the library and call :

```
boolean split = ResourcesCompat.getResources_getBoolean(this, R.bool.abs__split_action_bar_is_narrow);
```

If you don't use any library then you can go with Ahmad's answer but **only** if you don't use a library. This is because they use different values. The android framework seems to split the bar if the width is lower than 400dp, but for appcompat and ABS it's 480dp.